# Is it possible to disable application insights tracking in a specific web api controller?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I have an Asp.net core web api project and i've added the simplest configuration of application insights in Startup.cs file.

```
 services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
```

Everything is fine and the data is sent to Azure correctly, but now I need to stop tracking data from a specific controller because it makes a request to an external api and when it fails i'm able to control the flow but i dont want to see those error un application insights portal.

Comment: Hello, if the answer if helpful, could you please accept it as answer as per this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [telemetry processor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#create-a-telemetry-processor-c) to filter out the data from the specified controller, sample code like below:

```
public class CustomControllerFilter : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }

    public CustomControllerFilter(ITelemetryProcessor next)
    {
        this.Next = next;
    }
    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        RequestTelemetry telemetry = item as RequestTelemetry;

        if (telemetry != null)
        {
            //the test controller
            if (telemetry.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("/test/"))
            {
                return;
            }
        }


        this.Next.Process(item);
    }
}
```

Then register it in Startup.cs -> ConfigureServices method:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //other code
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

        //register it here
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<CustomControllerFilter>();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method to disable it and call on the controller. This method would include:

```
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.DisableTelemetry = true;
```

Another option would be modifying appsettings.json to control the logging done by ApplicationInsights. Something like the following in appsettings.json ensure Applicationinsights only sends traces for logs with severity >= Warning.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Trace"
      }
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    }
  }
}
```